# Coffeescript watch src directory to compile

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am doing this -

`$ coffee -c assets/js`

To compile all .coffee files into .js files in that directory. But i don't understand how I can watch the directory ?

I try this but get error -

```
$ coffee -wc assets/js

/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:287
      if (e.code !== 'ENOENT') throw e;
                                     ^
Error: watch EMFILE
    at errnoException (fs.js:648:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:676:11)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:704:11)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:256:27
    at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:85:25)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 37):

In one of my cake files I do this:

```
"coffee -o javascript/ -cw coffeescript/"
```

All of my .coffee files are in the coffeescript folder, and this compiles them into the same hierarchy in the javascript folder, as well as watching them.

It's from the [docs](http://coffeescript.org/). Hope it helps.

Comment: ya but those are different directories. I want to work in the same directory. So, same directory for both the source and the build.

Comment: Ah, it would seem that when you try to watch too many files an error is thrown: [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coffeescript/V3bpNeS2Pt0)

Answer (score 10):

Tested with CoffeeScript 1.7.1

in command line:

```
coffee -wc DIR
```

- w = watch
- c = compile